# Is there a way to make Python nested class instances within a class definition not break when I have to change a definitions location?

Tags: python, class, location, instance, composition

I'm using Python 3.10+.
I reviewed stackoverflow and couldn't find the exact problem discussed.  If I missed it, can you send me the link?

***PROBLEM***

I have the following folder structure:

folderA

--scriptA.py

In scriptA, I define class X

```
class X:
  def __init__():
     self.prop1 = Y()
     self.prop2 = somevalue
     self.prop3 = somevalue

class Y:
  def __init__():
      self.creationdate = dt.datetime.now()
```

When I print vars(instanceX), it shows the structure:

```
instanceX = X()
print(vars(instanceX)

{
    ...
    'prop1': <FolderA.ScriptA.Y object at 0x000asdff20323f0>,
    ...
}
```

I save this instance to a file.

Later, I rearranged my code so now the class definition of Y has moved to a FolderB.ScriptB.py.

Now when I open up the file containing the instance, the system returns an error essentially saying no module found.

I realized that it is because the instance of Y is tied to a specific location.

So what I did to fix it was recreate the old location of the definition so I can read the file, replace the value of the instance of Y property with the new definition, so now it is tied to the definition in the new location.

However, if down the road I have to rearrange my code again, it's going to break again.

I sense there is some best practice approach that I am breaking here.

How would I rewrite the code so that I don't have to worry about where I move my scripts or definitions around in the future so long as the definition exists somewhere in the codebase?  Or is that even possible?  Would I just have to avoid changing the location of class definitions in the future?

Comment: What use is the string representation of an instance of `Y` even if you *didn't* move the file?

Comment: When you say "I save this instance to a file" - the vital question is how you've saved the instance, and WHAT precisely is being saved. If you have an object with a rich distribution of attributes and methods, and you simply save the attributes, reloading those attributes alone won't restore the full behaviour of the object - you'd need to ally those attributes with the original methods that comprised the object if the newly loaded object is to regain its prior behaviour...

Comment: Apologies.  I simply saved the instance to a pickle file.  So I think it was attached to the original definitions when it was saved, which is why when I move the definitions location afterwards, it cannot render the attributes because it is looking for the definition in the old location.

Comment: I should've clarified.  The benefit of class Y is to store several different methods of representing a timestamp.  I forgot to include those properties in the class Y initialization definition.  But assume they were there.